# Deleted migration files and can't create new database model from scratch

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm trying to reset my database, I deleted all migration files but now when I create a migration it doesn't include anything in the `Up()`, no create tables, keys etc. I've rebuilt the solution and restarted Visual Studio and it still doesn't work.

I'm using model builder with code first to define table relationships.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to delete the {contextname}Snapshot.cs

In your .csproj file there must also be referenced that you removed the migration.

...
    `<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Migrations\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.cs" />
    </ItemGroup>`
...

I suggest you take the cli from entity framework -> remove-migration migrationName

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, do I add that line to say I removed the migration file or do I delete it? I have found this in the project file: <Compile Include="Migrations\Configuration.cs" />. Do I delete it?

Comment: the problem is that your up() function stays empty is that your project file includes the  <Compile Include="Migrations\Configuration.cs" />
i never deleted it by hand, i suggest you use cli
remove-migration Configuration